# Connect QGIS to the custom application server

Tags: qgis

I'm new to QGIS and investigating how to migrate one home made GIS application on QGIS.

The biggest difficulty for me now is to find the way how to plug QGIS to the application server that is being used now to fetch and save data.

What is the right direction to begin with?

Comment: What type of server is it?

Comment: It is .NetRemoting service. The idea is to have certain business logic between user and spatial DB. I'm looking for the best approach to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

you cant mix up differen things in it. If you are talking about sharing the data the its fine. you can use a WMS/WFS or just a postgis over a network will do job. if you are talking about a module such as finiding a shortest path. you need to port(actually write a new qgis plugin). QGIs provides two languages for the developer choice. C++/Python

Answer (score 0):

Since the question doesn't provide any detail it's really difficult to answer well.

Some things you could look into is WFS-T support which is already built into QGIS but will most certainly not be available on your server.

The source code of QGIS Cloud plugin might also be a starting point for how to tie QGIS to a server.